# electrorate badge wording: change possibly?

Tags: discussion, badges

This wording seems a bit ambiguous to me:
"Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

If you've voted **on** 600 questions, how can 25% be **on** questions? (Wouldn't 100% be on questions?)

Maybe 'in' should be used instead for the first instance:
"Voted in 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

Or, maybe add an 'actual' in there too:
"Voted in 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on actual questions"

or:
"Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on actual questions"

Comment: *"If you've voted on 600 questions, how can 25% be on questions? (Wouldn't 100% be on questions?)"* Not if you've voted on some answers too.  I don't see how adding "in" or "actual" clears things up.

Comment: No, because if you've voted on an answer, you haven't voted on a question, but the answer inside that question.

Comment: I'm sure someone's asked this before and received basically the same answer, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 5):

They are two separate requirements, and get separated as such:

1. > Voted on 600 questions

   Out of all the votes you've cast, at least 600 of them have been on questions.
2. > 25% or more of total votes are on questions

   Out of all the votes you've cast, at least 25% of them have been on questions.

Comment: Oh, so, "Voted 600 times and 25% or more are on questions" ?

Comment: No, "Voted 600 times" is different from "Voted on 600 questions". "Voted 600 times" includes votes on *answers* too.

Comment: ohhh... so if you voted 600 times, and 100% of those times were on questions, you'd obtain the badge? That's still weird wording!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few reads first time I saw it too.

As animuson has made clear, there are two separate requirements.
However, there's only one sentence, and while this can usually be fine, in this scenario the first requirement is also the same *topic* (question votes) as the second.
So it seems like the second requirement is *an additional reference* to the first requirement.

Two requirements with the issue/confusion highlighted in bold:

1. **Voted** on 600 **questions**
2. 25% or more of your total **votes** are on **questions**

Perhaps adding the word "your" and a comma could make it more clear and separate the two requirements:

> Voted on 600 questions, and 25% or more of your total votes are on questions

It's still not ideal, but perhaps a bit better and it's only a *small* change.
The "your" makes it read a bit more like "your total votes ever", rather than seeming like "total votes of the 600 votes" from the first part of the sentence.